CloudFront additional origin determined by path
I have a main static/spa web site being served from S3 via CloudFront (Main Site, Distribution A).
Route53 is routing my domain name to this Distribution A (example.com)
Now, I need a blog, which is a separate next.js site being served from Lambda. I've also created a second CloudFront distribution for this site using open-next where there quite a few origins and behaviors (Blog site, Distribution B)
Goal: Serve the blog site at the path example.com/content (so I gain seo benefits of being on the same domain).
i.e.
Route 53
|
|---> example.com (Domain)
      |
      |---> Distribution A (Main Site, S3 & CloudFront)
      |       |
      |       |---> /* (Serves static/spa content from S3, other than /content/*)
      |
      |---> /content
              |
              |---> Distribution B (Blog Site, Next.js on Lambda & CloudFront)
                      |
                      |---> /* (Handles all routes for the blog site)

My issue is this is not working via current setup.

I've created a new origin for Distribution A (which is the cloudfront url of Distribution B - the next.js blog site)
I've created a new behavior for Distribution A (which path setting is /content/* and uses the origin above, as well as a higher precedence value)
I've invalidated caching, and waited for propagation

There is no redirect whatsoever. example.com/content still routes to the main site's distribution (not the desired blog site).
I've turned on logging for CloudFront, and see some type of Miss/Error but no clear details.
#Fields: date time x-edge-location sc-bytes c-ip cs-method cs(Host) cs-uri-stem sc-status cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs-uri-query cs(Cookie) x-edge-result-type x-edge-request-id x-host-header cs-protocol cs-bytes time-taken x-forwarded-for ssl-protocol ssl-cipher x-edge-response-result-type cs-protocol-version fle-status fle-encrypted-fields c-port time-to-first-byte x-edge-detailed-result-type sc-content-type sc-content-len sc-range-start sc-range-end
2024-08-27  20:25:32    IAD12-P4    2344    MASK_IP GET d2eMASK.cloudfront.net  /content/*  200 -   Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/127.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36   -   -   Miss    9rvpqqZ07jk8qVGTViA3-JKRBORO2ixh66eEZLy9wkh9Fnx_EAGIpA==    example.com https   40  0.044   -   TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  Miss    HTTP/2.0    -   -   59468   0.044   Miss    text/html;charset=utf-8 -   -   -
2024-08-27  20:25:36    IAD61-P5    2471    MASK_IP GET d2eMASK.cloudfront.net  /content/2314   200 -   Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/127.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36   -   -   Error   UzsqNPHmBnrNU07SSYdLpCg4Ny9b6q3DJTmdgcTZvTJmiT1jna9w6w==    example.com https   1234    0.032   MASK_IP TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Error   HTTP/1.1    -   -   39800   0.032   Error   text/html;charset=utf-8 -   -   -
2024-08-27  20:25:32    IAD61-P5    2471    MASK_IP GET d2eMASK.cloudfront.net  /content/*  200 -   Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/127.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36   -   -   Error   zbFeQ5DN2w7VYTj0bCaxgKumFeGDj2Zr7XQ5Kq1CUCrH-q4-VVRkEg==    example.com https   1231    0.034   MASK_IP TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Error   HTTP/1.1    -   -   19518   0.034   Error   text/html;charset=utf-8 -   -   -
2024-08-27  20:26:08    IAD61-P5    2471    MASK_IP GET d2eMASK.cloudfront.net  /content/2314   200 -   Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/127.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36   -   -   Error   R4OwEnJ1_G1qjTFQxWHflmunLHCeM3eePasGRTsmD_Ta2xfsfpXruw==    example.com https   1260    0.008   MASK_IP TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Error   HTTP/1.1    -   -   9614    0.008   Error   text/html;charset=utf-8 -   -   -
2024-08-27  20:26:08    IAD61-P5    2471    MASK_IP GET d2eMASK.cloudfront.net  /content/2314   200 -   Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/127.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36   -   -   Error   dy9MfGsyqtLsgsv1ulLo08ovDWVBrYLNshmq_D8W-FUdOchRu51Tkg==    example.com https   1260    0.003   MASK_IP TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Error   HTTP/1.1    -   -   25192   0.003   Error   text/html;charset=utf-8 -   -   -

AWS Config in Pictures:
Distribution A

Origin setup for the blog site (on Distribution A)

Behaviors setup

